# Create Multiple Elements in tsx with return instead of copy paste

Tags: html, reactjs, clone, tsx

I am creating a Game and need multiple Squares with custom ID, I designed one with some Placeholder Attributes and wanna make it 16 times. Is there a more efficient way instead of pasting it 16 times?
This all ist in TypeScript with React.

Here you have the Code for 4 of the 16 Cards, is there any smarter way?

`    import React, { cloneElement } from "react";

```
const Cards = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <script></script>
         <div className="card">
          <h1>Click Me!</h1>
      <div>
        <script></script>
         <div className="card">
          <h1>Click Me!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <script></script>
         <div className="card">
          <h1>Click Me!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <script></script>
         <div className="card">
          <h1>Click Me!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

    </>
  );
};

export default Cards;


import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Scoreboard from "./components/Scoreboard";
import GameBoard from "./components/GameBoard";
import Cards from "./components/Cards";

const App = (): ReactElement => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <>
                <GameBoard />
                <Cards />
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/scoreboard" element={<Scoreboard />} />
        </Routes>
      </>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default App;
```

`

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Array.from` to create an array and pass in your desired length .

```
import React from 'react'


const Cards : React.FC = () => {

  return (

    <div>

      {
          Array.from({length : 16} , (_, index)  :JSX.Element => {
              return (
                <div key={index}>
                 <div className="card">
                  <h1>Click Me!</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
          })
        }
      </div>

  )

}



export default Cards ;
```